# Como faço para que o mapa tenha um raio em volta do ponto de localização especifico?

Tags: google-maps, maps-javascript-api, angular-google-maps

Como faço para que o mapa tenha um raio em volta do ponto de localização específico de mais ou menos 2 km? Exemplo abaixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]